# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "OS" with Samsung tts

Tags: android, exception, text-to-speech

I'm using Text to speech  in my android application.It is working Fine with Google TTs and espeak, But when i used with Samsung TTS it gives following Exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "OS"
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.speech.tts.ITextToSpeechService$Stub$Proxy.isLanguageAvailable(ITextToSpeechService.java:482)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$10.run(TextToSpeech.java:1084)

at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$10.run(TextToSpeech.java:1081)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:1329)

at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:570)

at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:561)

at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(TextToSpeech.java:1081)
```

Comment: For me Samsung device returns true on isLanguageAvailable but fails with exactly this exception later on during the setLanguage()

Comment: @MartinVysny any luck finding a workaround? I'm having the same issue with setLanguage(...).

Comment: No luck, sorry. All I thought of is to preach to the users, to spam Samsung to fix this issue ;)

Comment: When you changed the default engine to the google tts has it solved the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I have found that I get this exception also when I try to do something like `TextToSpeech.getDefaultVoice`, or `TextToSpeech.getVoices()`, or `TextToSpeech.getVoice()`.  I worked around this by not calling them, and instead working through the default Locale to get what I was trying to get via the Voices object.

So in my case I wanted to know the Locale so I could select a language, so I did the following

```
            Locale lTest = Locale.getDefault();
            res = mTTS.isLanguageAvailable(lTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this to avoid raising the exception.

```java
    int result = mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US);
    if(result >= 0)
        result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    else {
        Locale def = Locale.getDefault();
        result = mTts.isLanguageAvailable(def);
        if(result >=0 )
            result = mTts.setLanguage(def);
    }
```