# TTS causing IllegalArgumentException:Invalid int: "OS" during onInit in some Samsung devices with android api 23

Tags: android, text-to-speech, illegalargumentexception

After extensive research, I still can't find a workaround or solution for this issue.

TTS(Text-To-Speech) is causing IllegalArgumentException:Invalid int: "OS" during onInit in some Samsung devices with android api 23.

- Code:

  ```
  public void TTSInit(){
    mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

      @Override
      public void onInit(int status) {
          if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
              Log.i(TAG, "entered ttsinit");
              mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);   
          }
      }
    });
  }
  ```
- Stack Trace:

  ```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "OS"
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1624)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at android.speech.tts.ITextToSpeechService$Stub$Proxy.getVoices(ITextToSpeechService.java:796)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.getVoice(TextToSpeech.java:1769)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.access$1100(TextToSpeech.java:59)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$12.run(TextToSpeech.java:1581)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$12.run(TextToSpeech.java:1531)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:2337)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:747)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:737)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setLanguage(TextToSpeech.java:1531)
    at com.jisoopaullee.myengvocamanager.MainActivity$3.onInit(MainActivity.java:325)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:820)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.access$1900(TextToSpeech.java:59)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection$SetupConnectionAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TextToSpeech.java:2251)
    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection$SetupConnectionAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TextToSpeech.java:2206)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
  ```

Thanks.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730082/illegalargumentexception-invalid-int-os-with-samsung-tts

Comment: didn't work. Instead, I had to force the device to use Google TTS instead of Samsung TTS.

Answer (score -1):

```
        int iLcl=mTts.setLanguage(new Locale(stringsLcl[0],stringsLcl[1]));//
        if(iLcl == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE){
            Voice voiceLcl = mTts.getVoice();
            if(null == voiceLcl)
                l.a(800);// pardon, my logging
            Set<String> featuresLcl=voiceLcl.getFeatures();
            l.a(featuresLcl.size());
            for(String sLcl : featuresLcl)
                l.a("feature = "+ sLcl);
        };
        l.a(stringsLcl[0]+stringsLcl[1]);

        String myText1 = hashtumPoraMatnash;
        mTts.speak(myText1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```