# Android :TextToSpeech Invalid int: "OS" Exception

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I've used following code to set language to text to speech but geting following exception.

```
override fun onInit(status: Int) {
            if (textToSpeech == null || status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                isTextToSpeechInitialized = false
                return
            }

            isTextToSpeechInitialized = true
            if (textToSpeech!!.isLanguageAvailable(CountryConfiguration.locale) == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                textToSpeech!!.language = CountryConfiguration.locale
            }
            readNextFile()
        }
```

The exception is as follows:

```
  Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "OS"
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1625)

     android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setLanguage(TextToSpeech.java:1535)
```

Comment: `Invalid int: "OS"` .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730082/illegalargumentexception-invalid-int-os-with-samsung-tts